# Existing Server Storage Management Software Solutions?

Tags: open-source, infrastructure

I am in the process of trying to graphically represent all of our server racks. So when we receive a new server we can decide where this should be put and where a specific servers currently resides.

Are there any existing software packages that stores this kind of data already? I'd prefer open source ones if there are any but anything would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look around at this and the solutions suggested (thanks Node) and at the moment my feeling are using one of the following:

- [NVentory](http://opensource.vidavee.com/NVentory/) though I'm not sure my company will want to use ruby and rails as this would be our first product using this
- [Rackview](http://rackview.sourceforge.net/)
- Or more likely just [MS Office Visio 2007 Add-in for Rack Server Virtualization](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?familyid=3250331A-0116-4064-92D1-50B9B0727B75&displaylang=en) however this looks like it only links to excel and hopefully I can use excel to query a database.

I will update when I have played about with these tools and see what they can provide.

Comment: Since you feel like saying "thanks Node", I think an up-vote for him  would be in order. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you use [nagios](http://www.nagios.org) as monitoring application you could use [NagVis](http://www.nagvis.org) to create custom status maps e.g. a rackview of your servers.

[Example Screenshot](http://www.nagvis.org/sites/default/files/screenshots/nagvis-1.3-rack.png)

[RackMonkey](http://www.flux.org.uk/projects/rackmonkey/) seems to fit your requirements too.